# How to efficiently use Actix Multipart to upload a single file to disk?

Tags: rust, upload, multipart, actix-web

**TL;DR:**

I have issues getting my head around Actix Multipart when iterating over "data chunks" and saving them to a single file; all while not messing up Rusts error handling, efficient memory management and async processing.

**Details and Background:**

I know a bit of C++ and the basics REST API theory but have never implemented web services before. Furthermore, I am a complete newbie to Rust and want to create a simple file server using Actix as my first Rust project. This file server will run in simple container in Kubernetes where instances of this container can be added and removed at any time. Files are stored in a single directory which is shared between all container instances via a mounted volume. Each instance should use as little memory as possible.
The goal is to provide...

1. A simple HTTP GET API endpoint which focuses on maximum speed for single file downloading.
2. A simple HTTP PUT API endpoint which focuses on maximum robustness and safety for single file uploading.

There are a few twists like file optional file compression using zstd, hashing using xxhash128, Write-Ahead Logging or WAL (like in SQLite), and so on which will be removed from the code snippets for simplicity reasons.

I am also open for further suggestions for improvements that go beyond the Acitx Multipart issue.

**HTTP GET:**
I am not happy with it but it works.

```rust
#[get("/file/{file_id}")]
pub async fn get_file(file_id: web::Path<String>, data_path: web::Data<Config>) -> impl Responder {
    let mut file_path = data_path.data_path.clone();
    file_path.push('/');
    file_path.push_str(&file_id);
    if let Ok(mut file) = File::open(file_path) {
        let mut contents = Vec::new();
        if let Err(_) = file.read_to_end(&mut contents) {
            return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish();
        }
        HttpResponse::Ok().body(contents)
    } else {
        HttpResponse::NotFound().finish()
    }
}
}
```

**HTTP PUT:**
Everything within the while loop is absolute trash. This is where I need your help.

```rust
#[put("/file/{file_id}")]
pub async fn put_file(
    data_path: web::Data<Config>, mut payload: Multipart, request: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
    // 10 MB
    const MAX_FILE_SIZE: u64 = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
    const MAX_FILE_COUNT: i32 = 1;

    // detect malformed requests
    let content_length: u64 = match request.headers().get("content-length") {
        Some(header_value) => header_value.to_str().unwrap_or("0").parse().unwrap_or(0),
        None => 0,
    };

    // reject malformed requests
    match content_length {
        0 => return HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish(),
        length if length > MAX_FILE_SIZE => {
            return HttpResponse::BadRequest()
                .body(format!("The uploaded file is too large. Maximum size is {} bytes.", MAX_FILE_SIZE));
        },
        _ => {}
    };

    let file_path = data_path.data_path.clone();
    let mut file_count = 0;

    while let Some(mut field) = payload.try_next().await.unwrap_or(None) {
        if let Some(filename) = field.content_disposition().get_filename() {
            if file_count == MAX_FILE_COUNT {
                return HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(format!(
                    "Too many files uploaded. Maximum count is {}.", MAX_FILE_COUNT
                ));
            }

            let file_path = format!("{}{}-{}", file_path, "1", sanitize_filename::sanitize(&filename));
            let mut file: File = File::create(&file_path).unwrap();

            while let Some(chunk) = field.try_next().await.unwrap_or(None) {
                file.write_all(&chunk).map_err(|e| {
                    HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!(
                        "Failed to write to file: {}", e
                    ))
                });
            }

            file.flush().map_err(|e| {
                HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!(
                    "Failed to flush file: {}", e
                ))
            });

            file_count += 1;
        }
    }

    if file_count != 1 {
        return HttpResponse::BadRequest().body("Exactly one file must be uploaded.");
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}
```

Comment: Hi ... have you looked at the https://github.com/jacob-pro/actix-easy-multipart crate? It does what you are trying to do. Specifically look at the examples

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for the hint. I looked into it and actix-easy-multipart is deprecated. Nonetheless, its functionality was merged into acitx-multipart with minor changes. This looks promising from a simplicity perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out using the main actix-web crate.

Please be aware that this solution relies on the default actix multipart behavoir which creates a temporary file when recieving an uploaded file. Here is an important notice from the official documentation:

> The default constructor, [NamedTempFile::new()](https://docs.rs/tempfile/3.1.0/tempfile/struct.NamedTempFile.html#method.new), creates files in the
> location returned by [std::env::temp_dir()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.temp_dir.html).

I use [std::fs:rename()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html) to move this file to my target directory. This "temporary file" behavoir is usfull for me, since my disk storage is very performant and memory usage is my major concern. Also keep in mind, that std::fs:rename() will work smiliar to move "mv". So make sure that std::env::temp_dir() and your target destination are set to a path on the same filesystem to prevent a complete file copy.

```rust
#[derive(MultipartForm)]
pub struct Upload {
    file: TempFile,
}

#[put("/file")]
pub async fn put_file(
    config: web::Data<Config>, form: MultipartForm<Upload>) -> impl Responder {
    const MAX_FILE_SIZE: u64 = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10 MB
    const MAX_FILE_COUNT: i32 = 1;

    // reject malformed requests
    match form.file.size {
        0 => return HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish(),
        length if length > MAX_FILE_SIZE.try_into().unwrap() => {
            return HttpResponse::BadRequest()
                .body(format!("The uploaded file is too large. Maximum size is {} bytes.", MAX_FILE_SIZE));
        },
        _ => {}
    };
    
    let temp_file_path = form.file.file.path();
    let file_name: &str = form
        .file
        .file_name
        .as_ref()
        .map(|m| m.as_ref())
        .unwrap_or("null");

    let mut file_path = PathBuf::from(&config.data_path);
    file_path.push(&sanitize_filename::sanitize(&file_name));

    match std::fs::rename(temp_file_path, file_path) {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Ok().finish(),
        Err(_) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish(),
    }
}
```